# Match returning straight input in all but one case

Tags: return, rust, match

Let's say I have an enum like this

```
pub enum Status<T> {
  Error,
  NotStarted,
  Incomplete,
  Complete(T),
}
```

and I want to do this

```
match foo(x) {
  Complete(i) => Complete(bar(i)),
  Error       => Error,
  NotStarted  => NotStarted,
  Incomplete  => Incomplete,
}
```

i.e. only do something with it, if it matched one "special" option and return match input unseen otherwise. In my code this happens a lot.

Is there another way to do this in a shorter way? Probably something like this:

```
match foo(x) {
  Complete(i) => Complete(bar(i)),
  _           => _,
}
```

Comment: @paolo Actually it turns aout, that it is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just bind the other cases to a name and return that

```rust
match foo(x) {
  Complete(i) => Complete(bar(i)),
  other       => other,
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this, if `bar`'s return type is different from the the type of `i`? Currently I get an `error: match arms have incompatible types`

Comment: @TristanStorch I don't believe so.  In that case, if you're doing this frequently, you might want to define a `map` method on the `Status` enum itself.

Comment: I don't know, what exactly you mean by this. Could you give me a hint or link?

Comment: @TristanStorch Something akin to [`Option::map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) (see [its source code for reference](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#425-430)).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll have to give it some thought, but this might be the right thing

Comment: You may want to make sure your answer is also represented on the linked duplicate.